# Unassigned closeable stream

Tags: java, stream

I'm working with Eclipse Juno and as I'm writing the following code, Eclipse warns me about a possible memory leak :

```
String s = new Scanner( System.in ).nextLine();
```

Indeed, I never close the System.in stream. How does the JVM (jre7) handle this ? Is it a good use ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a false alarm, I believe.  Eclipse is confusing it with something like this:

```
String s = new Scanner(new FileReader("foo.txt")).nextLine();
```

which *does* leak a new Closeable each time you execute it.

But in your code, the underlying stream (`System.in`) is still reachable and usable.  Certainly, there is no *need* to close it from the "resource leakage" perspective.

---

> Indeed, I never close the System.in stream. How does the JVM (jre7) handle this ?

The `System.in` stream remains open until (presumably) the application exits.  But that is no different to the situation if you hadn't called `new Scanner(System.in)` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**My answer is invalid, see the comments for details.  OP, please accept another.**

The JVM will keep the resource open until you close it or the program exits.  Eclipse's warning looks to be a good one.  On Java 7 you can use the try-with-resources pattern:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

This will close the Scanner automatically at the end of the try block.

Comment: Your code sample is quite useless as it doesn't capture the return value of `nextLine`. The cleanest code would be achieved if this was enclosed in a method with `return scanner.nextLine();`. Another point: `Scanner` by itself doesn't acquire any resources, so as long as the underlying resource is properly managed, there's no harm. In this particular case harm would indeed be done by **closing** the `stdin`. OP's code is fine and Eclipse's warning is misplaced.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You're correct.  I'll vote to have my answer deleted.

Comment: A final note, for reference: the JVM will also close the resource at the time its managing object is GC'd, which may very well happen before the end of the program.

Comment: I believe that only happens if the object's finalizer calls .close, which varies per Closeable class.  Are you referring to a different mechanism?

Comment: Yes, I meant the finalizer. All java.io closeable classes are implemented that way, as far as I know, and very probably many more. It is correct to point out that this is not something inherent to the `Closeable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore this.

Since `Scanner` is also `Closeable` and `Scanner::close` also does a close on the underlying reader if that's also closable.

Below is the code of `Scanner::close`.

```
public void close() {
    if (closed)
        return;
    if (source instanceof Closeable) {
        try {
            ((Closeable)source).close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            lastException = ioe;
        }
    }
    sourceClosed = true;
    source = null;
    closed = true;
}
```